# Delete slice from a 3D numpy.MaskedArray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, masked-array

I have a 3D `numpy.MaskedArray` and I want to delete the 3rd slice. If I was a numpy.array I could just use the `numpy.delete` function, e.g.  `np.delete(arr, obj=3, axis=0)`. However, this function is not available for `np.MaskedArrays`. How can I do this in a pythonic way and without changing the array type?

Comment: There's nothing especially 'pythonic' about `np.delete`, other than the fact that it is a `numpy` function.  Under the covers it is just Python code, rather complex because it tries to be general purpose.

Answer (score 1):

My memory of `np.delete` code is that in your case it would do:

```
np.ma.vstack([ arr[:3], arr[4:])
```